Xcom in sparksubmit operator
Do we have the capability to push data to xcom from within a Spark application that is using sparksubmit operator?
Is this something that is available in the latest version?
Using airflow 2.5.3. Don't see the operator having any functionality as yet. Is using a custom operator by adding this functionality the only option?
